# Socket.io listeners are increases when page reload. Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

So if use an example from [socket.io](http://socket.io/docs/#using-with-express-3/4) but put the `io.on` function into `app.get`, listeners are increases. How can i solve this problem correctly? I was using a variety of solutions, but they are rather a "duct tape" than a right solution.
For example

```
socket.removeAllListeners();
```

or

```
function socketio() {
    var counter = 1;
    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
        if (!(counter)) {
            counter--;
            socket.emit('news', {hello: 'world'}, function () {
            });
            socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks and sorry for my English.

Server code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(80);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

function socketio() {
    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
        socket.emit('news', {hello: 'world'}, function () {
        });
        socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
}
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    socketio();
    res.render('socket.jade');
});
```

Client code

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' }, function(){
    });
});
```

After first page reloading

```
Server console.log
{ my: 'data' }

Client console.log
Object { hello: "world" }
```

Second reloading

```
Server console.log

{ my: 'data' }
{ my: 'data' }
{ my: 'data' }
{ my: 'data' }

Client console.log
Object { hello: "world" }
Object { hello: "world" }
```

And so on...

Answer (score 0):

This is because each time you load the route handler, you tell socket.io to add the event listeners again. socket.io listens to websocket connections on a separate channel, so you only need to run `io.on('connection' ...` once. Try this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(80);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('news', {hello: 'world'}, function () {
    });
    socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('socket.jade');
});
```

If you need to handle a particular user's websocket connection, you should manage the individual `socket` objects that come out of the `connection` handler. Each one is a user's connection.

Comment: Yes, but if i need to get a `req.session` within `io`. How can I do this without `app.get/app.use`?
`function dataInsert(req) {  
 io.on('connection', function (socket) {  
   socket.on('data', function (data) {  
    data.toString();  
    dataTasksInsert(req.session.user, data);  
   });  
 });  
}`